# Set initial scroll position failed

Tags: javascript, scroll, undefined, twine-game-engine

I'm using Twine, and I'm using this code to try to set the initial scroll position to the middle:

```
var scrollToMiddle = ($('#view')[0].scrollWidth - $('#view').width()) / 2; $('#view').scrollLeft(scrollToMiddle);
```

But it gives me the error: "Cannot read property 'scrollWidth' of undefined"

Why is this?

Comment: Try with `get()`: `$('#view').get().scrollWidth`

Comment: Now it says "Unexpected token ':'" Incidentally I just put your suggested code in a line above what I have: I don't really know how to use JavaScript, so I don't know if that is what you meant.